# elasticsearch -Where does it store my json data

Tags: json, hadoop, elasticsearch

I have just downloaded " Elasticsearch" and started using some basics. 
I have a doubt, `Where does it stores my json data ?` . for example in Hadoop we have HDFS and replication everything.

Like that where does the Elacticsearch stores the data. And how does it work , Where the index details resides ?

Answer (score 3):

**When started as service**

The path is */var/lib/elasticsearch/elasticsearch/nodes/0/indices/*

You can set the data path in elasticsearch.yml file which is located in */etc/elasticsearch/*

**When Started through bin**

The path is */elasticsearch_directory/data*

You can set the data path in elasticsearch.yml file which is located in */elasticsearch_directory/config/*

***This is for LINUX***

Answer (score 1):

Elasticsearch is built on top of the Apache Lucene Core text search and indexing library. http://lucene.apache.org/core/

Elasticsearch uses Lucene to index and store your data in Lucene index files, referred to as segments. There can be multiple segment files per Lucene index. Each Elasticsearch shard is a Lucene index. Here is a writeup of the Lucene file format:

http://lucene.apache.org/core/4_7_2/core/org/apache/lucene/codecs/lucene46/package-summary.html#package_description